# Using @inject annotation

Tags: java, dependency-injection

How to inject the dependency of  a class in another class, if both of them are in different maven projects.
I do not want to use the import statement as adding a import statement means I will have to add the dependency in pom.xml which is causing the cyclic dependency issue.

So I need to inject the dependency ay runtime using @inject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import only means your configuration file, whether it's an xml config or `@Configuration` annotated java classes, is on the classpath. It has nothing to do with maven. Maven manages module dependencies while spring manages class dependencies.

Let's assume you have 2 maven modules:

```
module A: my.project.artifact1
module B: my.project.artifact2
```

Module A has a bean `bean1` that needs to be injected to a bean in module B.

Module A has a dependency:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>my.project</groupId>
   <artifactId>artifact2</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And project b has some bean:

```
@Component
public class Bean2 {
   @Inject
   private Bean1 bean1;
}
```

If you're using component scan in module A and `bean1` is in your classpath - no problem. It will be injected to `bean2`. If not, you should define it in your XML:

```
<bean id="bean2" class="Bean2">
   <propery name="bean1" ref="bean1"></property>
</bean>
```

That's it. No need for dependency of `B` in `A`.

What you **should** have though (in most cases) is an interface that `Bean1` implements and resides in a third, common, module that both module A and B are dependent on.

Comment: Will try that..Thanks :)

Comment: @saxenka - I wrote `@Autowired` in the code example but I meant `@Inject` (they both do the same, but you asked about `@Inject`). I edited the answer now.